# MobileFirst 8.0 calling adapter from apps is connecting to localhost:6015/mfp

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I tried to run my apps local using simulator, it's all working fine.

When I deploy my apps to iPad and test, it fail on calling the adapter:

[image]

I checked the host configuration in config.xml and mfpclient.plist is not targeting localhost:

[image]
[image]

Can anyone help to pint out my mistake ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you do a cordova prepare after you registered your application? 6015 port is only when you do a preview.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your machine and iPad are on same network.When you are trying to run on  local server your machine and device should be on same network or IP .

Comment: Yes, my ipad and the mfp server is on the same network. So I expect the connection to the mfp server will be 172.20.82.94 instead of localhost.

Comment: Can you check adapter.xml file of your Adapter ?is it using same domain ?